# How do i count a specific column on the dashboard in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Below is how i view count of on my dashboard for all devices i store, where 'devices' are all devices am storing in my database. l want to view a count using a specific column name in a row. how do i do that!, any help?

> @inject('devices', 'App\Device')
>
> `<div class="number"><strong>{{ $devices->count() }}</strong></div>`

Comment: Make method in `\App\Device` class that returns wanted result, then call it in blade template with `{{ $devices->customMethod() }}`.

Comment: sum a column or count a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out that i had to do something like this:

> **{{ $devices->where('Type_ID',
>   'Laptop')->count() }}**

from: `<div class="number"><strong>{{ $devices->count() }}</strong></div>`

to something like this and it worked perfectly:

```
<div class="number"><strong>{{ $devices->where('Type_ID', 'Laptop')->count() }}</strong></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
$devices->where('column', 'matches')->count();
```

Comment: i tried that and never got the column name on view to count. how best can i view in blade with that line of code in the controller?

Comment: i have figured it out now thanks for the help bro 'Thumbs Up sign'

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this maybe..

```
$devices->select('yourColumn', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->groupBy('yourColumn')->get()
```